# Count where values match, and retrieve count and value Firebase and Vue

Tags: firebase, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore

I have a big list of registrations, which I wish to display in a top 5 less and most used list as here:
[image]

I do not have a clue as to what the query for such operation would look like with Firebase Cloud Firestore. To retrieve data from the collection in subject, I use this:

```
getUserRegistrations() {
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  var userUID = user.uid;
  db
    .collection("registrations")
    .orderBy("date", "desc")
    .where("uid", "==", userUID)
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      const userRegistrations = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        const data = {
          registration_id: doc.id,
          experience_id: doc.data().experience_id,
          uid: doc.data().uid,
          title: doc.data().title,
          date: doc.data().date
        };
        userRegistrations.push(data);
      });
      this.userRegistrations = userRegistrations;
    });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`limit()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) function to only list 5 documents:

```
db
    .collection("registrations")
    .where("uid", "==", userUID)
    .orderBy("date", "desc")
    .limit(5)
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      const userRegistrations = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        const data = {
          registration_id: doc.id,
          experience_id: doc.data().experience_id,
          uid: doc.data().uid,
          title: doc.data().title,
          date: doc.data().date
        };
        userRegistrations.push(data);
      });
      this.userRegistrations = userRegistrations;
    });
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. Do you know how I get the count of each occuring value match of the "title" attribute ?